# Proper way to remove a marker from Nutiteq map

Tags: java, android, nutiteq

As is similar to many other mapping APIs, the nutiteq map api contains a [`MarkerLayer`](http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/javadoc/index.html?com/nutiteq/MapView.html) that can be added to the map. It has a simple method for [removing markers](http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/javadoc/com/nutiteq/vectorlayers/MarkerLayer.html#remove%28com.nutiteq.geometry.Marker%29) (for example: `markerLayer.remove(myMarker)`).

I noticed that the [`Marker`](http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/javadoc/index.html?com/nutiteq/MapView.html) class inherits a method called [`detachFromLayer`](http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/javadoc/com/nutiteq/geometry/VectorElement.html#detachFromLayer%28%29), which originates in the [`VectorElement`](http://nutiteq.github.io/hellomap3d/javadoc/com/nutiteq/geometry/VectorElement.html) from which `Marker` extends. According to the Javadoc:

> This method is intended for vector layers. When element is removed from layer, it must be detached to drop the element-layer link.

**Question:** Since a `Marker` is a `VectorElement`, and a `MarkerLayer` is a `VectorLayer`, given the above Javadoc description, what is the proper way to remove a marker from the marker layer?

Would I be correct that the *proper* way is to **both** remove the marker from the layer (using `MarkerLayer#remove`), **and** to invoke `detachFromLayer`? Or is it sufficient to merely remove the marker from the layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `markerLayer.remove(myMarker)` , *detachFromLayer* is an internal method and you should not use it normally.

Comment: Understood. Does the same go for the `detachFromDataSource` method? I encountered that method after posting the question, and I noticed that, as an example, if I remove a marker, then add it back to the same layer, an exception is thrown indicating the element already exists in the layer's data source. I suppose what I'm curious about is (with both this and the original question) whether there is a potential for a sort-of memory leak if the internal data source is keeping a reference to the vector element (marker in this case). Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for noting - it turned out that exception on adding removed marker back was a bug in 2.3.0 release. Please check with latest snapshot where it should be fixed: https://repository-nutiteq.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/com/nutiteq/nutiteq-3d-sdk/snapshot/nutiteq-3d-sdk-snapshot.jar

Comment: Ah ha, good to know. Thanks for that, I will check out the snapshot.

Answer (score 3):

JaakL is correct, remove is the correct method to call. detachFromLayer/detachFromDataSource are internal methods and should not be called by application (they are reserved for custom layers/data sources). The issue you reported is actually a bug that is already fixed in the development snapshot and will be in 2.3.1 release (it is not in 2.3.1RC1 though). Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Ah ha, good to know. Thanks for that, I will check out the snapshot.